# Python :sort list of dictionaries based on key

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries

```
[{'abc':1},{'abcd':2},{'ab':1}]
```

Based on length of key list has to sorted

```
[{'abcd':2},{'abc':1},{'ab':1}]
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Will your dictionaries have only one key always?

Comment: @EdChum my keys are dynamic not the way they specified in the link

Comment: you can't sort regular dictionaries, except using ordereddict.

Comment: @thefourtheye dictionaries have only one key

Comment: @Marcin: this is sorting a *list* **containing** dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by the longest key:

```
l = [{'abc':1},{'abcd':2},{'ab':1}]
l.sort(key=lambda x: len(next(iter(x))), reverse=True)
print(l)
```

Comment: `lambda x: len(x.keys()[0])` would work too as `.keys()` return list of keys.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: not in Python 3, where `dict.keys()` returns a *dictionary view*. `next(iter(x))` is better as it works in both versions.

Comment: @TanveerAlam, not in python 3, I changed to `iter` anyway

Answer (score 0):

If u like to sort by 1st key it's gonna be this:

```
l.sort(lambda a, b: -cmp(len(a.keys()[0]), len(b.keys()[0])))
```

However if you want to sort by max key, here the answer:

```
def maxKeyLen(d): return max(len(k) for k in d.keys())
l.sort(lambda a, b: -cmp(maxKeyLen(a), maxKeyLen(b)))
```

Comment: when we haev list of dictionaries inside dictionaries  [{'abc':{'count':1}},{'abcd:{'count:2'}'}],  sorting this list based on 'count' , is it possible